# How to check if MethodDeclaration belongs to inner class

Tags: eclipse, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

Is there any way by using JDT ASTParser, by which we can identify if the method declaration is inside the Anonymous inner class?

I am creating a Eclipse plug-in to find unused public methods in a project. I am using a ASTVisitor on the MethodDeclaration node and then using the JDT search. The problem is that while traversing through each Java Class i am visiting MethodDeclaration of anonymous inner classes like Listeners. I need to avoid these methods.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and what if that anonymous class uses a method? If you don't see that, you may think the method is dead.   I think you don't want to skip the inner class.

Comment: I am not moving the inner classes out of my search scope. Actually i am looping through the project and getting java file conforming to certain naming standards. I am then parsing theses files using ASTParser and listing out the public methods. I then perform a reference search for each method with the whole workspace as scope. My requirement is that, i dont need to perform reference search for methods inside the inner class, as the files i am using only have ActionListeners, SelectionListeners etc as inner class.

Comment: I was able to identify if the method corresponds to a inner class by using : `node.getParent().getParent().getNodeType() == ASTNode.CLASS_INSTANCE_CREATION`. But not sure whether this will work in all cases. Stil to get any answers...

Comment: ... I'm not sure what a listener is; you seem to think this is some kind of specialized inner class. But if you want to avoid *just* those (and not anonymous classes that are NOT listeners) you need an additional check for "listener". Since I don't know how you recognize one, I can't provide any advice on how to check for it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Baxter. For you info, a Listener is an interface which listens to certain user events like selection, mouse-click etc. In my code i am using these Listener for capturing user inputs, by instantiating the Listener and implementing its methods. Actually, i suppose CLASS_INSTANCE_CREATION is the type for  class instantiation. But as the method i need to avoid is inside this instantiated inner class, i am able to track it. Though this is working fine from me, i believe this is not a general appraoch and will not work in all scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i found a solution. There is a AnonymousClassDeclaration ASTNode in ASTParser which denotes the anonymous inner classes in the Java file. When visiting such nodes we can specify that these nodes need not be visited entirely (by returning false).

```
public boolean visit(AnonymousClassDeclaration classDeclarationStatement) {

        return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If CLASS_INSTANCE_CREATION is the type of node for an anonymous class, that should work. I'm not a Java expert; seems to me there are several ways to create an anonymous class, so you need to check that this node type covers them all.

... doesn't your anonymous listener(?) class have to inherit/implement a Listener interface? If that's the case, you should be able climb over to the part of the tree near the CLASS_INSTANCE_CREATION that is the inherits/implements clause, and check that it really does implement/inherit what you expect. To do this right, you need full name and type resolution; just because an interface name is spelled "Listener" doesn't mean it is the one you intended

Comment: I am not directly implementing this interfaces. I instantiate classes which have already implemented this interface, and override the methods inside it. But as you have anwered, i still need to find out if the anonymous class inherits the Listener.